# My DVBT (it9135) doesn't work...Please Help

Tags: hardware, tv, dvb-t

My DVBT (it9135) doesn't work.

The output of `lsusb` command is:

```
me@mydesktop:~$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 048d:9006 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 

IT9135 BDA Afatech DVB-T HDTV Dongle

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and the output of `dmesg | grep dvb` command is:

```
[   15.013789] usb 1-1.2: dvb_usb_v2: 2nd usb_bulk_msg() failed=-110
[   15.133279] usb 1-1.2: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'ITE 9135(9006) Generic' in cold state
[   15.291005] usb 1-1.2: dvb_usb_v2: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw'
[   15.694003] usb 1-1.2: dvb_usb_v2: found a 'ITE 9135(9006) Generic' in warm state
[   15.694242] usb 1-1.2: dvb_usb_v2: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer
[   15.694586] dvb_usb_it913x: probe of 1-1.2:1.0 failed with error -12
[   15.694642] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_it913x
```

and output of `uname -a` is:

```
me@mydesktop:~$ uname -a

Linux odroid64 3.14.79-109 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 16 20:05:25 BRT 2017 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I asked this question in the Persian ubuntu forum but unfortunately  I have not received any answer.

Comment: The top of your `lsusb`output is missing (especially the `ID`), and you did not tell about your Ubuntu/kernel version, so it is difficult to answer. Please have a look at https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices/Full to find if it is supposed to work (ID and kernel version provided).

Comment: Can you indicate which kernel you are using? Have you tried the method set out [here](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/ITE_IT9135)